# Adding Multiple Columns with Different IF Statements

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Essentially, I am helping to setup a SharePoint site that another department will for reviewing contracts to make sure they are correct. There are many different choice columns with `"Correct" "Incorrect" and "N/A"` as options. I need to assign a point value to these columns, and they all add up to 100 points.

Normally I would do this with a simple IF statement. I would like to make the calculation all into one calculated column, but cannot get that to work. Not even sure if it can work.

I would like to avoid having over 40 columns designated just for finding scores, and then one for adding them all together. Is there a way to simplify these two calculated columns into one that also sums them together.

```
=IF([Column A]="Incorrect"0,3)
=IF([Column B]="Incorrect"0,5)
```

So if Column A is "Correct" it is worth 3 points, but Column B would be worth 5.

I'd like the one "Total Score" column that adds these all together. Is that possible? I feel I'm missing an easy solution here.

Comment: Are you saying that you will have Column 1 to 100 and each column will have three possible choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) you can do the following to do the calculation and condition in one column:

```
=SUM(IF([Column A]="Incorrect", 0, 3), IF([Column B]="Incorrect", 0, 5), ...)
```

Also you can use nested if-conditions, which could look like that:

```
IF([Column A]="Correct",3, IF([Column A]="Incorrect",0, IF([Column A]="N/A",1,0)))
```

This nested condition will set 3 points for "Correct", 0 Points for "Incorrect and 1 point for "N/A"

Comment: I will give this a shot. Positive I tried your first option, but maybe I didn't close my parentheses as I kept getting a syntax error. Looks so much simpler when someone else types it out!

Be back on Tuesday to let you know if this solves it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: This worked, thanks! I've marked your answer as the resolution.

Thanks again!

Comment: Nice :) No Problem.